# Measure of triangular area

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $\lambda\in[0,1]$, $\Omega=[0,1]^2$, $\vec{m}$ and $\vec{n}$ be two linearly independent vectors, $i\in\mathbb{N}$ and $h(t)$ the periodic extension of

$$\tilde{h}(t):=\begin{cases}
(1-\lambda)t &t\in[0,\lambda)\\
-\lambda(t-1) &t\in [\lambda,1].
\end{cases}$$

I would like to show that $$\mathcal{L}^{2}\Big(\big\{x\in \Omega\;|\;ik\leq i\boldsymbol{x}\cdot \boldsymbol{n} \leq h(i\boldsymbol{x}\cdot \boldsymbol{m})+ik\big\}\Big)\;\leq\tfrac{1}{i},$$
where $k$ is chosen such that the line $\boldsymbol{x}\cdot \boldsymbol{n}=k$ lies still in $\Omega$.

The shape of the region is triangular, but I am not sure how to compute the measure. Since the problem is very specific, I think I need a hint on how to tackle this problem, rather than a solution.

An example would be $$\boldsymbol{m}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 
0
\end{pmatrix},\;\boldsymbol{n}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
1
\end{pmatrix},\; \lambda=1/2,\;k=1/2,$$I suspect it should be enough to show it on a specific example?

Comment: Non-parallel and anti-parallel are two different things. Why is the anti-parallel in a parenthesis?

Comment: Sorry, english is not my native language. I meant to say that they are neither parallel nor anti-parallel.

Comment: I will change it into linearly independent.